# xdebug can't collect trace output

Tags: xdebug

I'm using xdebug to analysis my website performance .

here is my php.ini config informations:

```
zend_extension              = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll";

xdebug.remote_enable        = true;

xdebug.remote_host          = 127.0.0.1;

xdebug.remote_port         = 9000 ;

xdebug.profiler_enable      = on;

xdebug.trace_output_dir     = "C:\xdebug\trace";

xdebug.profiler_output_dir  = "C:\xdebug\profiler";

xdebug.auto_trace           = On;

xdebug.show_exception_trace = On;

xdebug.remote_autostart     = On;

xdebug.collect_vars         = On;

xdebug.collect_return       = On;

xdebug.collect_params       = On;

xdebug.show_local_vars      = On;

xdebug.default_enable       = On;

xdebug.remote_handler       = dbgp;

xdebug.max_nesting_level    = 10000;
```

In this situation, I can link phpstrom 9.0 to debug my PHP application .

But when I want to collect trace data in local file, apache will return http 502 error to browser and I don't know why this happen.